# Trying to pass a list from DAL through Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass a list from DAL through controller, I gather the SQL-data in a Datatable so I'm trying to change the DataTable to a List in the controller, but with no success.

This is my DAL method:

```
public DataTable findAllUsers()
{
    string queryText = "SELECT UserNbr FROM Users";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, con);

    con.Open();

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();

    return dt;
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public List<User> allUsers ()
{
    List<User> allUsers = DAL.findAllUsers.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Loop through each row, create a new `User` object, add to a `List` then return it from your `DAL`

Comment: Or use a ORM like entity framework to create the objects for you

Comment: What's the error? Is anything returned to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need something like this:

```
// This is a class that represents a row of your DataTable.
public class User
{
    public int UserNbr { get; set;}
    public User(int userNbr)
    {
        UserNbr = userNbr;
    }
}

public List<User> allUsers ()
{
    var users = new List<User>();

    // Create an instance of the DAL class.
    var dal = new Restaurang4.DAL();

    // Loop through the datatable's rows and create foreach of them 
    // a new User and then add it to the users list.
    foreach(var dataRow in dal.findAllUsers().Rows)
        users.Add(new User(dataRow.Field<int>("UserNbr ")));

    return users;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christos! But when I try this I get the following message for "DAL.findAllUsers()": Error: An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Restaurang4.DAL.findAllUsers(). Any idea why?

Comment: Please see my update and let me know. This is happening because we should create first an instance of the dal class and the use it's methods. If the class where static or the method `findAllUsers` where static, we wouldn't have experienced this.

Comment: Does the method in your `DAL` need to return a `DataTable` at all? Could you not return `List<User>` from there instead?

Comment: @Ric Of course it could return a `List<User>`. This is solely depends on the intentions of the developer.

Comment: Sorry @Christos that was aimed at the OP, just wanted to know if there was a dependency on the `DataTable`

Comment: @Ric not a problem at all dude :)

Comment: Now I get this error instead (the old error disappeared. ) http://i62.tinypic.com/ddjej6.png

Comment: Ric, no probably not, I tried to return a List form the DAL-method instead, but I didn't manage.. Maybe this is the best solution? Could you give an example of this? (You can just edit the code to the DAL-solution)

Comment: @SLI oops my mistake. I am sorry. See the updated one. Thanks.

Comment: @Christos, now the Field<int> gets an error "'object' does not contatin a definition for 'Field' and no extension method 'Field' accepting a first arguement of type 'object' could be found....

Comment: `Field()` is an extension method in the namespace `System.Data`, so make sure you have a `using System.Data` at the top of the class.

Comment: @SLI you may want to research each new error that arises instead of requesting hand-holding during each step. Don't turn this into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).